# Skype 4.2 webcam is green

Tags: 12.04, skype, webcam

I already install video4linux control panel and I already adjust the settings but the adjusted settings don't work for skype. The video was still green.

How can I fix this?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Lenovo s10-3.

Comment: Is it working fine for other application like `cheese`?

Comment: @guruprasad YES, it works fine with cheese

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Right click on skype icon
2. Click options
3. Video devices
4. Make sure everything's ok, an enable/disable auto-exposure(change it)
5. Close the window
6. Restart the computer

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also try GUVCVIEW webcam software. Code:

sudo apt-get install guvcview

It is a lightweight and handy webcam tool far better than cheese in my opinion, and you can adjust controls more easily in Guvcview. If you like it, and if it works for Skype video settings too, I suggest you get rid of Cheese package permanently.

With guvcview you can preserve the AUTOGAIN function (for a decent image), and at the same time you can disable LIGHT FREQUENCY FILTER so your webcam won't freeze when you're in a video conference. If you want to manually adjust image controls then you must uncheck the AUTOGAIN box first.